# Problem with cabal : cabal init does not create Main.hs

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am having a problem with Cabal that when I initialise a new project, Main.hs is not there.

Just following the documentation https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/getting-started.html#installing-the-haskell-toolchain

My cabal version is mentioned below.

```
cabal-install version 1.18.0.5
using version 1.18.1.3 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: You should probably upgrade your cabal, you are using one from 2014. The latest version is 3.6.0.0, but 3.4.0.0 is considered stable.

Comment: @Noughtmare Please consider making an answer for this question, as it allows the original poster to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an old version of cabal, as Noughtmare rightly pointed out!